# Specifying CNAME in cpanel for a subdomain, should change the url in address bar or not when the subdomain is visited in browser?

Tags: redirect, cname

I have a question related to CNAME settings done in hostgator (or in any other hosting provider) via their cPanel.

In hostgator, I created a subdomain abc.example.com, and then in DNS Editor, I replaced A record of abc.example.com with a CNAME record pointing to pqr.anotherhost.com.

My question is, if I try to visit abc.example.com in the browser, then:

1) Will the URL in the address bar change to pqr.anotherhost.com and the content of pqr.anotherhost.com page should be visible or not?

2) Will URL in the address bar must retain to abc.example.com, but the content of the webpage should be that of pqr.anotherhost.com?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve both the scenarios
1-If you turn on masking then the url will remain same but the content of target will be shown.

2- If you turn off masking then you will be redirected to the target page and the url will be changed.